# 404 when running PHPMyAdmin on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

I am getting a 404 when opening `localhost/phpmyadmin`.

I have installed Apache2, PHPMyAdmin, and MySQL, and configured the `apache2.conf` file, but still facing issues while accessing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redo the installation using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin`

Now as you are using Ubuntu 14.04 manually include the phpMyAdmin-shipped Apache Configuration file using the following commands :

`sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf`

`sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin`

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`

Source : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin